# How to put swipe tab views inside one of navigation drawer option

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, navigation

Updated code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.base_pager);
    FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(manager));  
    return rootView;
}




class HomeFragment extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public HomeFragment(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        if (item == 0) {
            //MapFragment.message("Map");
            fragment = new MapFragment();
        } else if (item == 1) {
            //SavedLocationsFragment.message("locations");
            fragment = new MapFragment();
        } /*else if (item == 2) {
        fragment = new FragmentC();
    }*/
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String title = new String();
        if (position == 0) {
            title = "Map";
        } else if (position == 1) {
            title = "savedLocations";
        }
        return title;
    }

}
```

I am getting error on this onCreateView method;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.base_pager);
    FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(manager));  
    return rootView;
}
```

The error are;

- The annotation @Override is disallowed for this location
- Syntax error on token "View", @ expected
- Syntax error on token "LayoutInflater", = expected after this token
- Syntax error on token "ViewGroup", = expected after this token
- Syntax error on token "Bundle", = expected after this token

Comment: well i have done this in one of my app, you can dex2jar my app and get the code. all you have to do is in your navigation drawer whatever fragment you open that will act as base for the next swipe tabs

Comment: I have the code for my drawer in my main activity class, so in this class where I am calling my Home Fragment, do I write the code for swipe tab?

Comment: no you don't, from navigation drawer you will open an empty fragment that will act as a host for the swipe-tabs you want to show, :) that would make your code easy to read and follow up

Comment: I am totally confused, could you please give me an example. I am fairly new to android and don't know all the syntax.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pk.nimgade.newyorksubway 
check this out, i believe i have done what you are looking for, tell me if you can you dex2jar, that would help you get my code, if you can't let me know

Comment: Where can I get the dex2jar?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/downloads/list

Comment: I have downloaded the the dex2jar but I am not sure how it works

Comment: add me in skype pankaj nimgade

Comment: Can we take it in decision instead? I am at work place and don't have the permission to download skype.

Comment: alright, i will right some snippet for your home fragment which will be host for you other fragments. remember you open your home fragment from navigation drawer. your home fragment is using viewpager to host swipe tabs,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your home fragment do this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.base_pager);
    FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(manager));      
    return view;
}




class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    if (item == 0) {

        fragment = new PhotoCommnFragment();
    } else if (item == 1) {

        fragment = new ShowRestaurant();
    } /*else if (item == 2) {
        fragment = new FragmentC();
    }*/
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String title = new String();
    if (position == 0) {
        title = "Map";
    } else if (position == 1) {
        title = "Restaurant";
    } else if (position == 2) {
        title = "Table 2";
    }
    return title;
}

}
```

now from this you would be able to call your child fragment of home, it like this

your mainActivity is mother then you home fragment is child of your mainActivity.
and in your home fragment is hosting Reasturant and Map Fragment. 
kindly check how to you dex2jar, if you can't i will mail you relevant code

Comment: I am getting few errors, I will update my post with the errors I am getting atm

Comment: @Android, pass your email address i will send you the entire project

Comment: jsmithk95@outlook.com

Comment: I got the email but no project is attached to it

Comment: are you accessing it in your office, if yes then you might have issues getting that attachment. i can see the attachment

Comment: Got the project, thanks. the file is giving me 1 error on this data = (int) params[0]; saying Cannot cast from Object to int

Comment: managed to fix the error. Btw, nice project. must have taken hell of a time to make that

Comment: I am glad that helped you, kindly accept answer if it helps you. Remember you always need to understand more and code will take care of itself.

Comment: How would use mapactivity without extending it. I need to extend fragment and am unable to extend the map activity. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting it, it is not a map activity, they are map images for my application. you do need to extend fragment for mapactivity. you did a good job resolving that error :). How is your project coming along