# Swipe tabs within fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer that loads a fragment in most cases when you  tap a drawer item.

I want to load a fragment that has swiping tabs withing the fragment.
i.e

nav drawer (Activity)

--- TabFragments (fragment)

------- Tab1 (fragment)

------- Tab2 (fragment)

Most examples I have seen show how you can add swipe tabs to activities, can someone please guide on how to do this for fragments.

I have actually got it working to the point wher i have a viewpager, and the FragmentPagerAdapter set using the answer in this question:

[How to put swipe tab views inside one of navigation drawer option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169093/how-to-put-swipe-tab-views-inside-one-of-navigation-drawer-option)

I can swipe through the fragments, however I want to have the tab titles at the top in the toolbar, but not sure how to do it given that I am doing this from a fragment

Comment: The best I can do is showing this sample, it was really helpful for me time ago! https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample

Comment: You want have fragment containing viewpager And handle it.?

Comment: @bryanc yes the viewpager goes in the main fragment and swiping changes the child fragment

Comment: I have this in my current project, will post here may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first i used a frameLayout for content(fragments) with id:"container"
in drawer item select handler method used :

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();   
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,MyFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

MyFragment contains ViewPager in its xml layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.NewDogActivity"
    android:id="@+id/coScroll">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
       >
             <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in `MyFragment` class:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewshop, container, false);
        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        View_PagerAdapter adp = new com.vinny.adapter.ViewShopPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adp);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```